# Laravel user is logged out whenever new release on elastic beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So i'm new to **AWS** and and finally created my successful pipeline connecting elastic beanstalk and bitbucket but there's one problem that **whenever i send a new release the user gets logged out of the application**. I want to know is that normal ? and if no then how can i prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably storing your sessions on the disk and making a new sessions folder for each release.

You can change the session driver, but it's easier to make a central sessions folder and symlink the `storage/framework/sessions` folder to it for each release.

If you're deploying to multiple instances/regions though the only option is to choose another driver. One with a separate server.

Comment: should database session driver solve this problem?

Comment: thanks guys i changed my session type database and it works like a charm.

Comment: @iruoy how would you go about achieving the symlink solution? I like the sound of this for a particular scenario where database doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @mgilberties We had the storage folder in one location and linked the storage folder of each release to that one. Pretty much like they did in the `deploy.sh` of this blogpost https://www.toptal.com/laravel/laravel-zero-downtime-deployment

`rm -rf storage && ln -sf ../storage .`